# response is invalid in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: spring-boot, response, interceptor, handlerinterceptor

I configure the interceptor in custom WebMvcConfigurer.

```java
public class RegisterInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        responseMsg(response,ResponseEnum.REGISTER_UN_AUTHORIZATION);
        return false;
    }
    public void responseMsg(HttpServletResponse response,ResponseEnum responseEnum) throws Exception{
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(responseEnum.getCode());
        ReturnMsg msg = new ReturnMsg(responseEnum);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(msg).getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I want to repsond to messages,but defeated
postman : Parse Error: Response overflow

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your customed response code (ResponseEnum.REGISTER_UN_AUTHORIZATION) is too large. And that large response code is not expected by the postman.
Check your ResponseEnum.REGISTER_UN_AUTHORIZATION code, it should comply with HTTP status code.